# What's the name of this Heteroptera bug from Toronto, Canada?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

My friend already identified it as belonging to the Heteroptera order, but I was wondering if anyone knows the name of the species.

Found in Toronto, Ontario, Canada, on July 21 2017, in a residential bathroom.

[image: Mystery bug]
[image: Mystery bug]

Comment: @BernardoRamos Yes, thank you, I forgot to add it, here it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is, indeed, a [Heteroptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera) bug.

Luckily, this is not a kissing bug (which could be infected with *Trypanosoma*), but just an *assassin bug*, from the Species [*Reduvius personatus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduvius_personatus). Its common name is [masked hunter](http://ento.psu.edu/extension/factsheets/masked-hunter).

Here is an image of the same bug, also in Ontario, from the [Canada Pest Control](http://pestcontrolcanada.com/) website:

[image: Assassin bug]

<sup>Source: http://pestcontrolcanada.com/5723-2/</sup>

And in this photo you can see the long rostrum, just like in your second photo:

[image: Assassin bug with visible rostrum]

<sup>Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fIBT7IJHn8</sup>

Finally, to see an assassin bug in action (a different species, though), have a look at this video from the Smithsonian Channel: https://youtu.be/hXFRAmWiaa4